# Why do I need to use systemd to set my timezone in RHEL7?

Tags: timezone, systemd, rhel7

I used to be able to edit /etc/sysconfig/clock, but now I need to use timedatectl, which I believe is a systemd command.

What has that got to do with booting the system?

Comment: Lennart jut had some fun time, that's all.

Answer (score 4):

There is only *one* place on a Linux system that is the source of truth regarding the system timezone for userland processes, that is `/etc/localtime`. And indeed, `timedatectl` is managing that file, creating a symbolic link to the appropriate zoneinfo file.

```
[root@yaungol ~]# ls -l /etc/localtime
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 23 Oct 17 00:55 /etc/localtime -> ../usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC
[root@yaungol ~]# timedatectl set-timezone Europe/London
[root@yaungol ~]# ls -l /etc/localtime
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 35 Feb 12 09:27 /etc/localtime -> ../usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/London
[root@yaungol ~]# timedatectl set-timezone UTC
[root@yaungol ~]# ls -l /etc/localtime
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 25 Feb 12 09:27 /etc/localtime -> ../usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC
```

Editing `/etc/sysconfig/clock` was a bad design to begin with, since it was redundant, (as mentioned before, `/etc/localtime` is what the system really uses!) and it's good that it's gone now.

If you don't wish to use `timedatectl` you can always manage the symbolic link yourself with puppet, ansible or whatever.

Comment: That's not *quite* right. The timezone can be set through the TZ environment variable as well. If that is set it will override the /etc/localtime file. See man 3 tzset.